# Expected method to read array element not found on object of type 'NSDictionary *'

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an album with 10 images, where I want the details of the image clicked. In this code `galleryResult` has all the details of the 10 images and I am trying to copy the details of the image I clicked to the variable `mediaDict`. The variables `galleryResult` and `mediaDct` is a dictionary. While doing this I get an error that shows `Expected method to read array element not found on object of type 'NSDictionary *`.

```
-(void)imageTapped:(UIGestureRecognizer*)gesture
{      
    UIView *photoImageView = (UIView *)gesture.view;
    int labelTag =(int) photoImageView.tag;
    mediadict = galleryResult[labelTag];
    [self presentGalleryWithImageAtIndex:photoImageView.tag];      
}
```

galleryResult printed :

```
{ data = ( { "comment_count" = 0; "dislike_count" = 0; "is_disliked" = 0; "is_liked" = 0; "like_count" = 0; "media_file_id" = 1366; "media_url" = "195/559812113_7511740_193F2CB1-CAA5-4A35-86B0-CAD0765FAFAD.jpg"; "media_url_thumb" = "195/thumb_559812113_7511740_193F2CB1-CAA5-4A35-86B0-CAD0765FAFAD.jpg"; "post_type" = MI; "userspost_id" = 26014; }
```

Comment: try [galleryResult objectAtIndex: labelTag] instead of galleryResult[labelTag]

Comment: can you print this `galleryResult`

Comment: no it is not working. showing error "No visible @interface for 'NSDictionary' declares the selector 'objectAtIndex:'"

Comment: is galleryResult is a dictionary?

Comment: Printing description of self->galleryResult:
{
    data =     (
                {
            "comment_count" = 0;
            "dislike_count" = 0;
            "is_disliked" = 0;
            "is_liked" = 0;
            "like_count" = 0;
            "media_file_id" = 1366;
            "media_url" = "195/559812113_7511740_193F2CB1-CAA5-4A35-86B0-CAD0765FAFAD.jpg";
            "media_url_thumb" = "195/thumb_559812113_7511740_193F2CB1-CAA5-4A35-86B0-CAD0765FAFAD.jpg";
            "post_type" = MI;
            "userspost_id" = 26014;
        }

Comment: @Indrajeet galleryResult is a dictionary

Comment: ok, for accessing dictionary object you have to pass key and it should be in String. Here you are passing integer.

Comment: @iOSer  no it is not working. showing error "No visible interface for NSDictionary' declares the selector 'objectAtIndex:

Comment: @Indrajeet thanku :)

Comment: Oh okay my apologies. I thought {galleryResult} was an array. can you please put forward the complete log for {galleryResult} unfortunately the one you shared is inconclusive

Comment: @iOSer       Printing description of self->galleryResult:
{
    data =     (
                {
            "comment_count" = 0;
            "dislike_count" = 0;
            "is_disliked" = 0;
            "is_liked" = 0;
            "like_count" = 0;
            "media_file_id" = 1366;
            "media_url" = "195/559812113_7511740_193F2CB1-CAA5-4A35-86B0-CAD0765FAFAD.jpg";
            "media_url_thumb" = "195/thumb_559812113_7511740_193F2CB1-CAA5-4A35-86B0-CAD0765FAFAD.jpg";
            "post_type" = MI;
            "userspost_id" = 26014;
        },

Comment: Not sure if the message is being truncated or something. The way I see it this is the dictionary { "comment_count" = 0; "dislike_count" = 0; "is_disliked" = 0; "is_liked" = 0; "like_count" = 0; "media_file_id" = 1366; "media_url" = "195/559812113_7511740_193F2CB1-CAA5-4A35-86B0-CAD0765FAFAD.jpg"; "media_url_thumb" = "195/thumb_559812113_7511740_193F2CB1-CAA5-4A35-86B0-CAD0765FAFAD.jpg"; "post_type" = MI; "userspost_id" = 26014; } and it should have an accessing key which I am not able to see here.

Comment: @iOSer { data = ( { "comment_count" = 0; "dislike_count" = 0; "is_disliked" = 0; "is_liked" = 0; "like_count" = 0; "media_file_id" = 1366; "media_url" = "195/559812113_7511740_193F2CB1-CAA5-4A35-86B0-CAD0765FAFAD.jpg"; "media_url_thumb" = "195/thumb_559812113_7511740_193F2CB1-CAA5-4A35-86B0-CAD0765FAFAD.jpg"; "post_type" = MI; "userspost_id" = 26014; }

Comment: can you shoot a mail @ iospranav1712@gmail.com regarding the same.

Comment: @iOSer OK please check your mail

Comment: Yup I received the mail. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On going through your log. It seems to me that `galleryResult` is a dictionary with a key `data` that contains an array of dictionary.

You probably want to access the data that is present within `data` key.

Please try `[galleryResult["data"] objectAtIndex: labelTag]`

Answer (score 0):

The variables galleryResult is really a NSDictionary? Int can't be the key of NSDictionary

Print all the keys for galleryResult.
If the key is an NSNumber, using

```
mediadict = galleryResult[@(labelTag)];
```

If the key is a NSString, using

```
mediadict = galleryResult[[@(labelTag) stringValue]];
```